# Mopub mobile web/javascript integration - multiple units

Tags: javascript, html, integration, mopub

this should be easy, adding another object in the units array. But when I do, I get an error, as the API can not find the container with the given ID.
Screenshot of the [Firebug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjjxL.jpg).

I have 3 units and the unit IDs are properly given and associated with containers. 
window.Mopub gets initialized and populated, it's and array of three objects, here's a screenshot of [DOM - window.Mopub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZP8s.jpg) :

Integration code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.mopub = [{
    ad_unit: "2acca42ca4e746689c1d41cd1d5587e7",
    ad_container_id: "mopub_top", // Specify the div or container to which you’d like to the mobile web tag
    ad_width: 320,
    ad_height: 50,
    keywords: "", // Optionally pass keywords as a comma separated list
  }, {
    ad_unit: "c3eb9222c0fb459997b2ab3bfb4bde0d",
    ad_container_id: "mopub_mid", // Specify the div or container to which you’d like to the mobile web tag
    ad_width: 320,
    ad_height: 50,
    keywords: "", // Optionally pass keywords as a comma separated list
  }, {
    ad_unit: "a2a35dc504334ccd8e244076a4ee7518",
    ad_container_id: "mopub_floater", // Specify the div or container to which you’d like to the mobile web tag
    ad_width: 1,
    ad_height: 1,
    keywords: "", // Optionally pass keywords as a comma separated list
  }]; // To load additional ad units, add another object into the array.

  (function() {
    var mopubjs = document.createElement("script");
    mopubjs.async = true;
    mopubjs.type = "text/javascript";
    mopubjs.src = "//d1zg4cyg8u4pko.cloudfront.net/mweb/mobileweb.min.js";
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(mopubjs, node);
  })();
</script>
```

The application is a classic mobile HTML5 website.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi, @Alex did you find a way around this problem. If so, please let me know  I am also stuck in this situation.